# Applet is stuck in loading

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, applet

I'm having a problem with an applet that gets stuck on the loading and nothing is shown on the console.
I use this applet twice in my webpage, it's the same applet but only called with different parameters in another part of the html page.

When i launch my applet for the first time its gets stuck, second time after terminating the java process and launching it again it works perfectly on both parts of the page.

i'm using the  tag.

```
<applet  code="recapplet.AudioApplet"
         archive="RecApplet.jar"
         height="40"
         width="990"
         id="app">
         <param name="layout" value="h" />
         <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
         <param name="rapport_id" value="#{dyna.gen_rap_id}"/>
         <param name="etab_param" value="#{dyna.etab_param}"/>  
         <param name="user_id" value="#{dyna.user.userId}"/>  

 </applet>
```

What possibly could be the problem.

Comment: What console are you referring to? `System.out` or the browser's JRE console?

Comment: java console yes the System.out ?

Comment: Those are two different consoles. `System.out` is what you'll see in your IDE, or server logs. The JRE (or applet) console is a popup window that shows up (when enabled) after the applet is launched. Which is it?

Comment: But when you use System.out in an Applet and you enable the Java Console you can see the System.out.println coomands output in that console taht u have enabled, do you agree ?

Comment: You'll see applet load-related problems in the java console. If the browser is having any problems with your applet, the JRE console is where you'll find pointers

Comment: i'm pretty sure you mean the following http://support.skillsoft.com/customer/progress/progresspage/sunjre.htm

Comment: so what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a **bug** in java plugin in chrome, it's already [reported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366075), i had to restrict my applet on Firefox users only unfortunately. hoping for future [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) updates and fixes.